# jQuery add plain html .after() and .before()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have some html element and I want to add some closing tags before it like

`tag.before("</div></div>");` 
and then re-open it by adding proper tags after like

`tag.after("<div class='one'><div class='two'>");`

But it seems to not be working. It creates tags and auto close them, and it dont add closing tags at all.

Why I need this?

I need some elements to be dircet child of body and I cant modify html by hand, so I want it to close all tags that its inside and then to reopen them with proper .classes

My function to do it is (but I'm not sure if it matter anyhow)

```
//function makes element dircet child of 'to' argument. It closes all parents and reopens'em
$.fn.escape = function(to) {
    return this.each(function(){
        var t = $(this);
        var parents = [];
        var escaped = false
        var actualParent = t.parent();

        //div to store cleared from content parents html
        var virtualDiv = $('<div class="hide"></div>');

        //while not walked to given root parent
        while ( !escaped ) {
            var parent = actualParent;
            if ( parent.is(to) || !parent.length) { //check if there is parent and if its the one we look for
                escaped = true;
            } else {
                parents.push( parent.clone().html('').prependTo(virtualDiv) );  //prepend clone of parent with cleared content to wirtual div
                actualParent = actualParent.parent();   //remember actual parent                
            }

        }

        //get html from virtual div and remove all closing tags from it
        var newOpenTags = virtualDiv.html().replace(/<\/\S+>/g, '');


        //basing on tag-type of each parent, generate closing tags
        var closeTags = "";
        for (var i = 0; i < parents.length ; i++) {
            closeTags = closeTags + "</" + parents[i].get(0).tagName.toLowerCase() + ">";
        }

        //put closing tags before element and put reopen tags after it
        t.before(closeTags);
        t.after(newOpenTags);
    })
}
```

In other words. How to add closing tags before some element and  add opening tags (withot auto closing them) after it.

Comment: create a fiddle please

Comment: why not `yourDiv.html("</div></div>"+yourDiv.html+"<div class='one'><div class='two'>")`?

Comment: vladkras as only inner content of div changes in your soultion during .html() - Div will still be inside another div.

Answer (score 0):

`before` and `after` does not inject html, it appends elements. What you want to do is [wrap()](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/) elements.

Comment: Or append/prepend for example, if you wanna insert childs.

Comment: @artistandsocial That makes no sense. That would be the same issue what the OP is doing, and it is not doing what the OP is trying to do.

Comment: I didn't write before/after?